# Getting coordinates of surface nodes using pyvista

Tags: python, pyvista

I'm wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to apply pyvista to extract the  surface nodes of a 3D object. For example, suppose I have a collection of points that builds out a sphere, including 'interior' and 'surface' points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
max_rad = 1
thetavec = np.linspace(0,np.pi,N)
phivec = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,2*N)
[th, ph] = np.meshgrid(thetavec,phivec)
R = np.random.rand(*th.shape) * max_rad

x = R*np.sin(th)*np.cos(ph)
y = R*np.sin(th)*np.sin(ph)
z = R*np.cos(th)

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z.flatten(), '*')
```

Now I'd like to apply [pyvista's](https://docs.pyvista.org/) [extract_surface](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyData.extract_surface.html) to locate the 'nodes' that live on the surface, together with their coordinates. That is, I'd like for extract_surface to return an array or dataframe of the coordinates of the surface points. I've tried to build a polydata object just with the vertices above (see [link](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyData.html) and section 'Initialize with just vertices')

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `extract_surface()` doesn't extract the surface in the sense that you think it does. Finding the exterior surface of a point cloud is a known difficult problem. You almost certainly have to have well-defined assumptions of your surface. If it's convex then you can triangulate it to get the convex hull. For concave surfaces it can get messy. See e.g. [this github discussion](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/discussions/1589). What is your real use case like?

Comment: ok thanks Andras. Yes it sounds like what I want is the exterior surface of a point cloud. I've been applying some convex hull code, but I thought pyvista could do the job for me. It has proven to be quite difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've confirmed in a comment that you're looking for a convex hull, you can do this using the [`delaunay_3d()`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.DataSetFilters.delaunay_3d.html#pyvista.DataSetFilters.delaunay_3d) filter. The output of the triangulation is an `UnstructuredGrid` that contains a grid of tetrahedra that fills the convex hull of you mesh. Calling `extract_surface()` on *this* space-filling mesh will give you the actual exterior, i.e. the convex hull:

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

# your example data
N = 50
max_rad = 1
thetavec = np.linspace(0,np.pi,N)
phivec = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,2*N)
[th, ph] = np.meshgrid(thetavec,phivec)
R = np.random.rand(*th.shape) * max_rad

x = R*np.sin(th)*np.cos(ph)
y = R*np.sin(th)*np.sin(ph)
z = R*np.cos(th)

# create a PyVista point cloud (in a PolyData)
points = np.array([x, y, z]).reshape(3, -1).T  # shape (n_points, 3)
cloud = pv.PolyData(points)

# extract surface by Delaunay triangulation to get the convex hull
convex_hull = cloud.delaunay_3d().extract_surface()  # contains faces
surface_points = convex_hull.cast_to_pointset()  # only points

# check what we've got
surface_points.plot(
    render_points_as_spheres=True,
    point_size=10,
    background='paleturquoise',
    scalar_bar_args={'color': 'black'},
)
```

(On older PyVista versions where `PolyData.cast_to_pointset()` is not available, one can `convex_hull.extract_points(range(convex_hull.n_points))`).

The result looks like this:

[image: spherical point cloud of coloured spheres, colorbar has label "vtkOriginalPointIds" ranging from 10 to about 5000]

Playing around with this interactively it's obvious that it only contains points from the convex hull (i.e. it doesn't contain interior points).

Also note the colouring: the scalars used are called `'vtkOriginalPointIds'` which are what you would actually expect if you tried to guess: it is the index of each point in the original point cloud. So we can use these scalars to extract the indices of the points making up the point cloud:

```py
# grab original point indices
surface_point_inds = surface_points.point_data['vtkOriginalPointIds']
# confirm that the indices are correct
print(np.array_equal(surface_points.points, cloud.points[surface_point_inds, :]))
# True
```

Of course if you don't need to identify the surface points in the original point cloud then you can just use `surface_points.points` or even `convex_hull.points` to get a standalone array of convex hull point coordinates.

Comment: Hi Andras, could you also tell me how to get the dataframe of the x,y,z surface node coordinates.. Thanks!

Comment: @jim it's not clear to me what you mean by "the dataframe". As I mentioned at the very end, `surface_points.points` is an `(n_hull_points, 3)`-shaped array where the three columns are the `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates of each point. You can turn this into a dataframe or any data structure you like. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: yep.. thanks again, Andras!.. for some reason, i missed the last part of your post above..